# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, pom.xml, spring-security-6

I have included tomcat in my pom

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.32</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and when I run the spring boot application, I get the following message:

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt
> was made from the following location:
>
> ```
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.customizeMaxHttpRequestHeaderSize(TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.java:264)
> ```
>
> The following method did not exist:
>
> ```
> 'void org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.setMaxHttpRequestHeaderSize(int)'
> ```
>
> The calling method's class,
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer,
> was loaded from the following location:
>
> ```
> jar:file:/home/kamil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/3.1.0/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.0.jar!/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/embedded/TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.class
> ```
>
> The called method's class,
> org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol, is available from the
> following locations:
>
> ```
> jar:file:/home/kamil/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.32/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/org/apache/coyote/http11/AbstractHttp11Protocol.class
> ```
>
> The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following
> locations:
>
> ```
> org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol: file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.32/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol: file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.32/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar
> ```
>
> Action:
>
> Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains
> compatible versions of the classes
> `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer`
> and `org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol`

and when I remove it, the compiler doesn't see `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`, `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse`, and `javax.servlet.http.FilterChain`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the tomcat dependency. Spring Boot BOM is going to provide it for you. Change `javax` to `jakarta` as they were replaced in Spring Security 6.